# Bootstrap not responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is it me or is Twitter bootstrap just not responsive at all using LESS?

One a test site I've set the following:

```
    // Articles

.article {
    .makeRow();        
}

.article-content {
    .makeColumn(7);

}
```

On resizing the page I'm getting horizontal scroll bars.

A quick check of the CSS shows the width of my article-content column to be 540px; not matter what my screen size.

Comment: are you including the responsive.js?

Comment: Yes responsive.js is included. As well as responsive.less

Answer (score 0):

The makeColumn mixin outputs the static grid. Try this instead:

```
.article-content {
   #grid > .fluid .span(7)
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm using .container which is fixed, not container-fluid

Comment: Sorry, I read your question as wanting to resize the column width as the browser is resized, which requires a fluid grid.Is there a media query in your css?